# Error while creating local repository in GitHub

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I have installed GitHub Desktop for Windows. When i try to create a new local repository using GitHub Desktop. It gives me an error as "Failed to create repository.
An error occurred while creating the repository. You might need to open a shell and debug the state of this repo."

Answer (score 4):

Had the same weird issue.  Try this from PowerShell/GitBash:

`git config --global user.email "you@example.com"`

`git config --global user.name "Your Name"`

For me, these values were not set because I did not log into my GitHub account during the GitHub Desktop install.

GitHub Desktop auto commits .gitignore and .gitattribute when you create a new repo, so the committing without setting these configs is probably causing this error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run Github with sufficient privileges. Try to run command shell as administrator and create repository in it.